# Python Find duplicates in 3 csv file

Tags: python, csv

How do I find duplicates that occur across 3 csv files?
So far I can find duplicated across 2 files.

```
import csv

with open('tidyforms.com.csv', 'rU') as master:
    master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)))

with open('jotform.com.csv', 'rU') as hosts:
    with open('similar.csv', 'wb') as results:    
        reader = csv.reader(hosts)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        writer.writerow(next(reader, []))

        for row in reader:
            index = master_indices.get(row[0])
            if index is not None:
                message = 'FOUND in master list (row {})'.format(index)
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it in four steps

1. Open file A, store values in master dictionary.
2. Open file B, check if any value of B is already present in master dictionary.
3. Add values of B in master dictionary.
4. Open file C, check if any value of C is already present in master dictionary.

Looking at your code, you already implemented steps 1 and 2.

Comment: In the end, the master directory will have the duplicates of A & B, but will not necessarily be a duplicate in C.